# Can I register a new user & authenticate while I am signed in my account? (Firebase auth)

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a scenario where I need to give a user some "extra" rights so that he is able to add new users (I am not familiar with Cloud functions and that would take some time for me to learn it, I need a quicker solution).

So, when the user registers a new user to Firebase, can he stay signed in and sign in with the new user account at the same time? Or is it something impossible?!

I know in most cases this is not the approach that I should take but in this one, I don't care so much of security, I just want to get it done.

Comment: I don't think you will find anything "quick".  You're going to need a backend with security controls for this.

Comment: @DougStevenson is it too risky to let the users sign in with just a passcode? Whats the wrost that can happen? This platform will be provided to doctors that are fighting COVID-19 and I need to implement something that patients can login very quickly without entering email and password like in every other platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest solution I can think of is to keep a state in a `users` database.
You can keep a state under user like :

```
users: {
  uid: {
    type: 'doctor', // or normal
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i decided already to do something like this. Patients will have to register themselves usign their personal email and a new password BUT only if they have a pincode provided by their doctors, otherwise they cant register without that pincode.